# How to use Deprecated NDK in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to include `.so` files in my Android Studio project inside `.jniLibs` folder but getting below error, how can I overcome it?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
>   Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.

I couldn't find `gradle.properties` anywhere? Where can I find or are there any work around?

Thanks

Comment: Try https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html ...

Answer (score 6):

In Android-Studio,gradle.properties can be accessed by the following drop-down list of views.[image: Drop Down Box in Android Studio]

After selecting the Project view,expand your project name and open your gradle.properties Tab .
[image: gradle.properties]

In the editor window enter

> android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

Now,you will be able to use the current NDK.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, you can create it.